# 2 foreach in 1 table is not work correctly

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, foreach

I'm try to loop 2 query inside one table . both query had 10 records . so i put my first foreach (or looping) before **TR** tag ..

here is example of the table that i want to create :

```css
.table, th, td { border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan=2><center>Out Of Stock</center></th>
            <th colspan=2><center>Sales By Qty</center></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>      
            <tr>
             <td>Data 1 from 1st Query</td>
             <td>Data 1 from 1st Query</td>
             <td>Data 1 from 2nd Query</td>
             <td>Data 1 from 2nd Query</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>Data 2 from 1st Query</td>
             <td>Data 2 from 1st Query</td>
             <td>Data 2 from 2nd Query</td>
             <td>Data 2 from 2nd Query</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
             <td>Data 3 from 1st Query</td>
             <td>Data 3 from 1st Query</td>
             <td>Data 3 from 2nd Query</td>
             <td>Data 3 from 2nd Query</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>Data 4 from 1st Query</td>
             <td>Data 4 from 1st Query</td>
             <td>Data 4 from 2nd Query</td>
             <td>Data 4 from 2nd Query</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I don't know how i can make my table like that with data from my database..

so i tried and put the first Foreach out the TR tag and close it after /TR tg. so as we can see there is 4 TD /TD inside TR /TR . so i put the second foreach in the middle between 4 TD /TD .

just like this :

```
        <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan=2><center>Out Of Stock</center></th>
            <th colspan=2><center>Sales By Qty</center></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>   
          <?php foreach($First_Data as $row){?>   
            <tr>
             <td>Data 1 from 1st Query</td>
             <td>Data 1 from 1st Query</td>
         <?php foreach($Second_data as $row){?>
             <td>Data 1 from 2nd Query</td>
             <td>Data 1 from 2nd Query</td>
         <?php }?>
            </tr>
          <?php }?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

and the result was not perfect and i guess  my foreachs are in the wrong place .

and here u can see the result of my try :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#customers {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

      <table id="customers" >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan=2><center>Out Of Stock</center></th>
            <th colspan=2><center>Sales By Qty</center></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD STRAW 70 ML BANDED 4</td>
        <td>89%</td>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD STRAWBERY MANGGO LF</td>
        <td>88%</td>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD BLUEBERRY 250 ML</td>
        <td>85%</td>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD MIXED BERRIES 250 ML</td>
        <td>85%</td>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD BLUEBERRY 70 ML BND4</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD MIXED 70 ML BANDED 4</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <tr>
        <td>YOLITE C+100 ORANGE </td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <tr>
        <td>YOLITE C+100 ORIGINAL</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD BANANA LF</td>
        <td>83%</td>
        <tr style="background-color: yellow;">
        <td>CIMORY YD PLAIN 250 ML</td>
        <td>82%</td>
        <td>YD-004</td>
        <td>390</td>
        </tr>
        <td>YD-005</td>
        <td>363</td>
        </tr>
        <td>YD-006</td>
        <td>248</td>
        </tr>
        <td>YD-002</td>
        <td>240</td>
        </tr>
        <td>YD-008</td>
        <td>153</td>
        </tr>
        <td>YD-069</td>
        <td>137</td>
        </tr>
        <td>YD-072</td>
          <td>132</td>
        </tr>
        <td>YD-015</td>
        <td>111</td>
        </tr>
        <td>YD-010</td>
        <td>111</td>
        </tr>
        <td>YD-001</td>
        <td>72</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

</body>
</html>
```

only one row (yellow background) is correct and the others are not . i dont know why . maybe my foreach is not correct or i put it in the wrong place .

and here what i want to achieve but i dont know how :

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
#customers {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
#customers td, #customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}
#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
     <table id="customers" style="width: 80%" >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan=2><center>Out Of Stock</center></th>
            <th colspan=2><center>Sales By Qty</center></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD STRAW 70 ML BANDED 4</td>
        <td>89%</td>
        <td>YD-005</td>
        <td>363</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD STRAWBERY MANGGO LF</td>
        <td>88%</td>
        <td>YD-006</td>
        <td>248</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD BLUEBERRY 250 ML</td>
        <td>85%</td>
        <td>YD-002</td>
        <td>240</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD MIXED BERRIES 250 ML</td>
        <td>85%</td>
        <td>YD-008</td>
        <td>153</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD BLUEBERRY 70 ML BND4</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>YD-069</td>
        <td>137</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD MIXED 70 ML BANDED 4</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>YD-072</td>
        <td>132</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>YOLITE C+100 ORANGE </td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>YD-015</td>
        <td>111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>YOLITE C+100 ORIGINAL</td>
        <td>84%</td>
        <td>YD-010</td>
        <td>111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD BANANA LF</td>
        <td>83%</td>
        <td>YD-001</td>
        <td>72</td>
        <tr>
        <td>CIMORY YD PLAIN 250 ML</td>
        <td>82%</td>
        <td>YD-004</td>
        <td>390</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

can someone tell me how and i'll be so thankful..
and sorry if my English is not really good because its not my mother tongue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, your logic is missing something because the second loop is running within the first loop, so you're creating a lot of TDs within the same TR.

In order to achieve what you want, I suggest merging the two arrays, then looping a single array.

```
<?php
$merged_array = [];
foreach($First_Data as $key => $row) {
    $merged_array[$key] = ['first' => $row];
}

foreach($Second_data as $key => $row) {
    $merged_array[$key]['second'] = $row;
}

/// HTML
?>
<tbody>   
    <?php foreach($merged_array as $key => $data){?>   
        <tr>
            <td><?=$data['first']['yourcolumnname'] ?></td>
            <td><?=$data['first']['yourcolumnname2'] ?></td>
            <td><?=$data['second']['yourcolumnname'] ?></td>
            <td><?=$data['second']['yourcolumnname2'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php }?>
</tbody>
```

Alternatively, if you're 100% sure that the keys between the two arrays are the same you can also do the following, shorter version without merging the two arrays:

```
<tbody>   
    <?php foreach($First_Data as $key => $row){?>   
        <tr>
            <td><?=$row['yourcolumnname'] ?></td>
            <td><?=$row['yourcolumnname2'] ?></td>
            <td><?=$Second_data[$key]['yourcolumnname'] ?></td>
            <td><?=$Second_data[$key]['yourcolumnname2'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php }?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: thank you so much bro .. i did as ur code and its work perfectly .. i really appreciate u for the answer .. 
bro i wanna ask what if the records are not equal ? the code still work correctly . right ?
FYI: i took the first way  not the shorter version .  :)

Comment: This really depends on how your tables and queries are structured. With both methods, they go in order, so if both tables are sorted in the same way and have the same IDs you should be OK.

Otherwise, you need to use an ID of the object as a way to understand if the $first_data and $second_data refer to the same object.

Comment: is there any way to handle the foreach  with unequal data ?. for example the first query have 10  records and the second only 5records.
can we handle it to echo 0 or let cell of table  empty if the foreach looping after 5 records did not find any second data? ..

Comment: you can use `isset` to check if the value is there or not without throwing any warning before printing it

Comment: i use isset to check if the value is there so echo value if not echo 0 and it works .. thank sir i learned a lot from u and thank u again for helping me out.. u r the best :)